# Take a picture and share it with one voice command using Google Glass Mirror API

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I just started using the Mirror API with a PHP web server.  Is there anyway to integrate a voice command with my app that when said, Glass will take a picture and automatically share the picture with my server?

From what I read so far, it doesn't seem possible to access the camera with anything other than the default "Take picture" command.  I also don't see a way to have Glass commit two actions (in this case take a picture and then share it) with one voice command.  Is there any way to do the above with the Mirror API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the current features provided by the Mirror API. If this is a feature you're interested in using, file it in the official [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

However, you can implement this functionality with the GDK.